# MVC 5 DropDownListFor Database Linq;

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, selectlist

Can anyone please tell me how to write Controller for C# (`public ActionResult DropList()`) for  Drop Down List generate Linq   I want convert this `SELECT DISTINCT CouName FROM Locations;` to Linq for my drop down list dynamically  generate.

Chtml page  how do I write in  `@Html.DropDownListFor("")`
Models.Location

Comment: Show the model you want to bind to

Comment: Location
public int LocationId { get; set; }
 public int OrderId { get; set; }
public string CouriersName { get; set; }

Comment: So do you want to bind to `LocationId`? Is `CouName` an int?

Comment: int LocationId 
string CouriersName with DISTINCT key eg SELECT DISTINCT CouriersName FROM Locations;

Comment: You not making sense. Do you mean you want to bind the selected value to the property `CouriersName`? (you can only bind a dropdown to one property)

Comment: I want show only drop down list Couriers Name  this is my sql quarry SELECT DISTINCT CouriersName FROM Locations;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you model is named `MyModel`

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
  var couriers = // get your couriers from the database using your query
  // Is better to assign this to a property in your view model, but ViewBag will do for now
  ViewBag.CourierList = new SelectList(couriers);
  var model = new YourModel();
}
```

View

```
@model YourModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CouriersName, (SelectList)ViewBag.CourierList)
}
```

Comment: must everyone use a freaking viewbag

Answer (score 2):

This code will generate a select list from an IQueryable GetAll() method, or you could use it on your entity directly using `from c in _context.Set<Location>()`

```
public SelectList GetAsSelectList()
{
    var locs = from c in GetAll()
               select new
               {
                   Id = c.Id,
                   Name = c.Name
               };
   return new SelectList(locs, "Id", "Name");
}
```

Where Id is the Value field and Name is the Text field of the selectlist options.

This would be assigned to a model property:

```
var model = new MyModel
{
    LocationList = GetAsSelectList();
}
```

You would pass the model to your View, and use DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MyModel.Location, Model.LocationList)
```

Your model would also have a `Location` property which you would set to display a default value if you wanted to do that.

Comment: How do I use  DISTINCT key? for example  SELECT DISTINCT CouName FROM Locations;

Comment: `return new SelectList(locs.Distinct(), "Id", "Name");`

Answer (score 1):

As far as i have understood, you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult DropList()
{
    List<SelectListItem> objResult = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var result = dbContext.Locations.Select(x=>x.CouName).Distinct().ToList();
    foreach(var item in result)
    {
      SelectListItem temp = new SelectListItem();
      temp.Text = item;
      temp.Value = item;
      objResult.Add(temp);
    }

    ViewBag.DropdownResult = objResult;

    return View();

}
```

Dropdown in view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.ModelLocations, ViewBag.DropdownResult  as List<SelectListItem>)
```

Please modify the code as per your need.

Comment: viewbag, yet again

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
...
public static List<SelectListItem> GetItemsForDisplay(string listName)
{
    //your data access function should return a list of objects
    return DAL.Table.SelectByName(listName)
        .Select(x=> new SelectListItem{Text=x.DisplayName, Value=x.ID})
        .ToList<SelectListItem>();
}
```